# How to let a ScheduledExecutorService run a Runnable ahead of the scheduled time?

Tags: java, scheduling, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to run a particular job (implemented as an ordinary `Runnable`) periodically once in a minute (using method `scheduleAtFixedDelay()`).

Occasionally, however, I would like it to wake up immediately, invoke the `Runnable` and then return to its ordinary policy (i.e. wait 1 minute again).

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I've checked the API of the `ScheduledExecutorService` and its superclasses, but so far didn't find anything suitable.

Of course I could resort to some other method, like pass the same `Runnable` to a separate Thread created for the exceptional purpose, but using a method of the `ScheduledExecutorService` would be more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember the [ScheduledFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) from your call to schedule.

If you then want to run it ahead of time, call [future.cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)), submit the Task again for immediate execution and then schedule it again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this!
By "submit the Task again for immediate execution" you think of the ScheduledExecutorService's execute(Runnable) method? 
If yes, this has one disadvantage, namely that (according to the docs) it is allowed to execute the task in the thread of the caller, which would not work for me. But let's see.

Comment: No, i meant [ExecutorService.submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)), which your queues your task to be executed as soon as there is a free Thread in the Executors thread pool

Comment: Also the docs for execute state it MAY be executed in the callers thread - depending on the Executor implementation you chose. If you wont choose an Executor implementation that does this (and frankly, I don't even know one) then this will not happen.

Comment: Thanks again, Michael, you helped me a lot. 
For now, I decided to add another thread to my executor's pool so I do not even have to cancel the Future related to the primary thread when I need to run an immediate job in between. (This shortens the time between job invocations, of course, but this does not harm in my case.) 
But I'll observe how it all behaves over time - maybe cancelling and restarting a single thread proves the superior solution. 
Thanks again!